# How to insert a new column in between columns in dataframe

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas

I need to insert multiple new columns in between columns in a dataframe

**Input dataframe:**

```
  PC GEO BL RL JanTOTAL  BL RL FebTOTAL
   A USA  1  1        2   1  1        2
   B IND  1  1        2   1  1        2
```

**Expected Output dataframe**

```
PC GEO Jan-Month        BL RL JanTOTAL     Feb-Month        BL RL FebTOTAL 
A  USA  2019-01-01       1  1        2    2019-02-01         1  1       2
B  IND  2019-01-01       1  1        2    2019-02-01         1  1       2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow this example:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['a']=[1]
df['b']=[2]
print(df)
df['Jan-Month']=datetime(2019,1,1)
df['Feb-Month']=datetime(2019,2,1)
print(df)
df=df.reindex(columns=['Jan-Month','a','Feb-Month','b'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   a  b
0  1  2

   a  b  Jan-Month  Feb-Month
0  1  2 2019-01-01 2019-02-01

   Jan-Month  a  Feb-Month  b
0 2019-01-01  1 2019-02-01  2
```

Comment: if i have 10 rows... will the "Jan-Month" column automatically have 10 rows of data?

Comment: No,  you need use a list, example:`df['Jan-Month']=[datetime(2019,1,1),datetime(2019,1,1),datetime(2019,1,2)] ` this is simple